# Fixed Points of Function from Rationals to Reals

Tags: functions, contest-math, rational-numbers

Consider a function $f$ from the positive rationals to the reals such that $f(x)f(y)\ge f(xy)$ and $f(x+y)\ge f(x)+f(y)$. Further assume this function has a fixed point greater than $1$. Prove this function fixes every point in its domain. (Found this on the IMO website and am sadly unable to solve thus far.)